# gitea ask for `gitea` password on TortoiseGit and SourceTree

Tags: git, gitea

I have a Manjaro system running `gitea` server. Now when I tried to do something with the repos on the server, eg. cloning or pushing, using TortoiseGit or SourceTree, the server will ask for a password for the account `gitea`.
[image: SourceTree]

When I do the same operation using the command line client, it would work just fine.
[image: Cli]

Also I have tried SSH into the system using `gitea` account and it looks good I think ...
[image: ssh using gitea account]

In the client machine, I have a private key loaded using `pageant` agent. TortoiseGit and SourceTree also have the key setup.

So what else I should do to get the git over ssh working?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `sshd` service is not configured to accept `ssh-rsa` public key algorithm. When trying to login, the key is rejected.

I have to add `ssh-rsa` algorithm to the `sshd_config` file as per below.

```
#/etc/ssh/sshd_config

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Then reload the configuration file.

One lesson learnt: read the log before start complaining.